# SocketIO NodeJS Gamemode Type emit

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm new to socketIO and my site is going to have 2 game modes, my plan was to make 2 scripts for each game mode, however thinking about it I would prefer to have one script do it all. I currently have it setup so the script emits to everyone connected. Is there a way to emit to users that are in a specific array or something...

I currently send data like this

```
io.emit("updateTimeLeft", runTime);
```

The thing that I'm confused about is, I'm doing theses on events in my script that are broadcasting to everyone. How would I get the specific sockets to send to...

Could I save the users socket in an array and then just list throw them and send the data I need? I don't know if this would work though. Any suggestions?

Comment: read the socket io documentation especially for namespace and rooms . I think this is what you're looking for http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam is right. you should use rooms (which is a built-in solution in socket.io) for each 'group'.

Example code:

```
  socket.join('myroom');
```

From now on, you can emit events to all sockets that are in 'myroom' this way:

```
io.to('myroom').emit('some event'):
```

Comment: That's amazing, I didn't even know that was a thing! Thanks!